# mySQL: Updating multiple values in a record with a SELECT from another table

Tags: sql, mysql

Trying to sort out the correct syntax for this `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE `foo` 
   SET (`x`, `y`, `z`) = (SELECT `x`, `y`, `z` 
                            FROM `bar` 
                           WHERE `id` = 'baz');
```

In the actual query, there are ***165*** columns so I very much do not want to have to do `x = x` for each column.

The columns are not a perfect match so `SELECT *` is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL you can add multiple tables to an `UPDATE` like this:

```
UPDATE `foo`, `bar`
SET `foo`.`x` = `bar`.`x`, 
    `foo`.`y` = `bar`.`y`, 
    `foo`.`z` = `bar`.`z`
WHERE `id` = 'baz';
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  

I made a test like so:  

UPDATE `test` SET 
`test`.`unique_id` = `store_import`.`unique_id`,
`test`.`synced_on` = `store_import`.`synced_on`
FROM `store_import` WHERE `store_import`.`entry_id` = 137

This gives error 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `store_import` WHERE `store_import`.`entry_id` = 137' at line 4 

Can you see where the problem lies?

Comment: Yeah I already changed the solution since I posted it. I mixed up MySQL and MSSQL. The current version is the one. :-)

Comment: Ah well.  Thanks.  Will take a long time getting all 165 columns into query!

Comment: You may want to alias the tables to speed up your input.

UPDATE foo a, bar b
SET a.x=b.x, a.y=b.y ......

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update items in foo where foo.id = bar.baz?

```
UPDATE foo JOIN bar
SET foo.x=bar.x, foo.y=bar.y
WHERE foo.id=bar.baz
```

Comment: Note JOIN is the same as , in list of table.